# PayPal Rest API. Why Agreement Id IS not Set

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I'm using PayPal REST API to create agreement. I wonder why there is no id in the response when billing agreement is created. Only execute token is present in **return_url**.

When payment is created an id is returned.

**Request**

`POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-dotnet 0.11.0 (core=1.6.0;lang=DOTNET;v=4.5;clr=4.0.30319.34014;bit=64;os=Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
Authorization: Bearer A015NObhWZJY-ZZHdSmMvYL7GFA6A-pY7pK4zV1J8wysWJE
PayPal-Request-Id: 98a56a18-2306-4301-a366-e53a5db54536
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 246
Expect: 100-continue`

```
{"name":"plan \"PN123\" subscription","description":"plan \"PN123\" subscription with payments every 12 months.","start_date":"2015-02-06T16:58:56z","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"plan":{"id":"P-2Y404528U1543832BL7HBW6A"}}
```

**Pretty Request Json**

```
{
  "name":"A plan \"PN123\" subscription",
  "description":"plan \"PN123\" subscription with payments every 12 months.",
  "start_date":"2015-02-06T16:58:56z",
  "payer":{
     "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "plan":{
     "id":"P-2Y404528U1543832BL7HBW6A"
  }
}
```

**Response**

`HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=374466
Paypal-Debug-Id: 739b28e849ee7
SERVER_INFO: paymentsplatformserv:v1.payments.billing-agreements&CalThreadId=501225&TopLevelTxnStartTime=14b5fce3a78&Host=slcsbpaymentsplatformserv3001.slc.paypal.com&pid=22725
Content-Language: *
Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 16:52:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1174`

**Pretty json from response**

```
{
  "name":"plan \"PN123\" subscription",
  "description":"plan \"PN123\" subscription with payments every 12 months.",
  "plan":{
     "id":"P-2Y404528U1543832BL7HBW6A",
     "state":"ACTIVE",
     "name":"PN123",
     "description":"plan \"PN123\" subscription",
     "type":"INFINITE",
     "payment_definitions":[
        {
           "id":"PD-8RD12495MY6350633L7HBW6I",
           "name":"Regular Payments",
           "type":"REGULAR",
           "frequency":"Month",
           "amount":{
              "currency":"USD",
              "value":"20"
           },
           "cycles":"0",
           "charge_models":[

           ],
           "frequency_interval":"12"
        }
     ],
     "merchant_preferences":{
        "setup_fee":{
           "currency":"USD",
           "value":"0"
        },
        "max_fail_attempts":"0",
        "return_url":"http://example.com/Subscription/Renew.aspx?result=ApproveAgreement",
        "cancel_url":"http://example.com/Subscription/Renew.aspx?result=CancelAgreement",
        "auto_bill_amount":"NO",
        "initial_fail_amount_action":"CONTINUE"
     }
  },
  "links":[
     {
        "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4R936998H4630535M",
        "rel":"approval_url",
        "method":"REDIRECT"
     },
     {
        "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-4R936998H4630535M/agreement-execute",
        "rel":"execute",
        "method":"POST"
     }
  ],
  "start_date":"2015-02-06T16:58:56z"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the Id when the payment gets executed, on paypal as your payment type.

1. Create [Billing Agreement](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/master/sample/doc/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithPayPal.html). You will get an EC-Token, and URL
2. On [Success, Execute Billing Agreement](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/master/sample/doc/billing/ExecuteAgreement.html), and

You could run the [samples attached](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples) with the PayPal-PHP-SDK, to try out before implementing the code yourself. Also, most of the sample code could be copy-pasted to get started easily.

Here are the screen shots from the samples: 
1. Created Agreement. Use the URL pointed in dark black line
[image]
2. Executed Agreement. As you can see, it has the agreement ID.
[image]

Comment: You are right. But scenarios of creating and executing of agreements differs from that I can see for payments. When a customer approves a payment its Id can be found as query string parameter in return url, so it is possible to retrieve payment information before it is executed.

Comment: Agreed. Its something that we have noticed before, and raised to the internal team accordingly. They are trying to keep it with the norms as of Payments. However, in the mean time, this will definitely work too. I will update this thread, when it is available.

Comment: I still cannot see how could I link the user from the agreement with the user of the successful execution of the agreement :(

Comment: @DiegoPamio I know this is late but in case someone else reads it. You want to use the ec-token. It gets generated when you create the agreement and it gets sent back to the server once the agreement approved so you can link the two.